# How can I combine these two columns in access

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

I am attempting to combine two columns (from separate tables) in an access query based on the value of 2 other columns in the tables (semester and student_name in this instance), for instance if I had the following:
[image]

and

[image]

how could I make a query to get the final result of:

[image]

where the third and fourth semester (only the third and fourth) sections of some_data have been combined based on student_name (there may be some names that are in one table, but not in another, etc, although that is not shown in these examples). I am not very experienced with access queries at this point in time, so I am having a difficult time accomplishing this. Any help is much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Which table takes precedent? If there are semester 3 values for the same student in both `Sheet1` and `Sheet2` which value goes into `sheet3`? Are ou wanting to Update `Sheet3`, insert new records into it, or is `Sheet3` actually a view?

Comment: @Brad hello, semester 3 & 4 would be blank in sheet 2, so the semester 3 & 4 values would be taken from sheet 1 and inserted into the blank spaces in sheet 2 (if the student names match), which would result in the output that is seen in sheet 3 (sheet 3 is just an example I had made of what the query output would look like regarding how the data is combined). Sheet 2 will always have those blank spaces for semester 3 & 4, so there would not be any situations where there would already be data residing there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE Sheet1 INNER JOIN Sheet2 
ON Sheet1.semester = Sheet2.semester
And  Sheet1.Student_name = Sheet2.Student_name
SET Sheet2.Some_data = Sheet1.Some_Data
Where Sheet1.semester in (3,4)
```

If you just want to see the results before they are applied you can click the `Datasheet View` button instead of the `Run` button.

If you want to leave your two tables intact and just have a view you can do this:

```
Select Sheet2.semester
, Sheet2.student_name
, Nz(Sheet2.some_data,Sheet1.some_data)
From Sheet1 INNER JOIN Sheet2 
ON Sheet1.semester = Sheet2.semester
And  Sheet1.Student_name = Sheet2.Student_name
```

with an optional `where` clause

```
Where Sheet1.semester in (3,4)
```

The [`Nz`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/advanced/nz.php) function here uses data from the first parameter unless that parameter is null, in which case it uses the value from the second parameter.

Comment: thanks! although one thing, is there a way to make it just display the results (the sheet2 with the cells replaced) instead of having it actually go replace the values in the sheets themselves? other than that though it works perfectly

Comment: excellent. one thing though, when I go to use it, I get a prompt asking for sheet2.some_data http://i.imgur.com/5qCKCrc.png after which I get the following results http://i.imgur.com/eP1A4EV.png (if I had typed in 123 for the prompt), is it possible to make it use the values from sheet1 again like it had in the first example that you made? sorry for all of the requests, you are very helpful though!

Comment: Sorry, fat fingers. It said `some_date` not `some_data`

Comment: oh lol, surprised I had not caught that. works perfectly nonetheless, thanks again for your help, much appreciated!

Comment: hello, sorry for pestering you again, but when I run the following query http://i.imgur.com/ujVuDyK.png, and get the following results http://i.imgur.com/fYJ7ajD.png, is there a way to include the rest of the contents of sheet2, so for instance I would get this as the final result http://i.imgur.com/vipWiQt.png

Comment: Don't have any `where` clause and change your `Inner Join` to a `Right Join` (Include all results from the table to the right (in terms of reading order) and include only those results from the other table where the join condition is met).

Comment: would there still be a way to limit it to just altering semesters 3 and 4 though (and ignoring the rest of the semesters that may have blank entries [I am applying this to a different set of data, that may include blank cells in other semester, which would not be changed)?

Comment: Is just removing the `where` clause not giving you the results you want (while retaining the `inner join`)?

Comment: im mostly just looking for a way to make it ignore the other semesters , so say for instance if semester 5 in sheet2 has some empty cells, that are not empty in sheet1, the sheet2 cells will be left as is, instead of replacing the empty cells with the values from sheet1. Although if that is not feasible/easy to do, thats perfectly fine as you've been an immense help already ready, I appreciate your time

Answer (score 1):

something like

```
select semester, student_name, max(some_data) from
(select semester, student_name, some_data from sheet1
union all
select semester, student_name, some_data from sheet2)
group by semester, student_name
```