# comparing values from two tables to update a third

Tags: ms-access

Im trying to update a field in table c based on the results of a comparison between table `a` and table `b`. It goes like this:

table `a` contains the patient name, status and description of their status.
- This is a complete table meant for comparison.

table `b` contains the patient name and status. 
- This table is added to every so often.

table `c` is the target table which needs to have a particular field updated based on the results from table `a` and `b`.

My logic goes like this, so far:

```
UPDATE tblc
SET patntStatus to results from comparison of table a & table b.
```

I know I need a JOIN but am unclear as to whether I need one or two - for example join `a` and `b` or join the results of `a` and `b` to `c`?

I think the first one is more correct so what is the proper syntax for the update?

Thanks

**UPDATE

Have added the SQL statement that displays what i want to to add to table c

```
SELECT STATUS, STATUS_DESCRIPTION
FROM tbla INNER JOIN tblb ON     
tbla.STATUS = tblb.STATUS
WHERE tblb.STATUS = tbla.STATUS;
```

Comment: Set everything up as a SELECT in the query design window. Play around until you are getting what you want and then change to Update. If you still have a problem, get back with the sql from the statement.

Comment: have updated my question with the SQL

Comment: That does not seem to make sense. You have joined on status which means that status=status, so you do not need WHERE. Also, just poick the table that has status and status description, you do not need the tow tables based on the above. Finally, how will you join to the third table?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: [How can I combine these two columns in access](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14816218/726127) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close to what you need. I don't know what you want to update in `C`, but assuming that you want `Staus_Desc` in `tblc` to match `Status_Description` in the comparison of `A` and `B`:

1. Save your SQL in a query (e.g. `qry_A_B_Compare`)
2. Create an UPDATE query with the following SQL:

:

```
UPDATE tblc 
INNER JOIN qry_A_B_Compare ON tblc.Status = qry_A_B_Compare.Status
SET tblc.Status_Desc = [Status_Description];
```